# About the isotriviality of pencils of plane curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $F$ and $G$ be coprime complex homogeneous polynomials in three variables of the same degree $d\geq 4$. Suppose that a general member of the pencil $\{F+tG=0\}\subset \mathbb{P}^2$ is smooth.

**Which are the tools one can use to verify whether this pencil is isotrivial?**

Comment: The Kodaira-Spencer map comes to mind.

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer but rather a lengthy comment.

A necessary condition for the pencil to be isotrivial is that a smooth member in that pencil has a non-trivial automorphism: By blowing-up the base points, $\mathbf{P}^2$ is birational to the total space of an isotrivial family $f : X \to \mathbf{P}^1$ of curves of genus $\ge 2$. Let $C$ denote a smooth fiber of $f$.
As $f$ is isotrivial, there exists a Galois cover $B \to \mathbf{P}^1$ (with the Galois group denoted by $G$) and a $G$-action on $C$ such that $f$ is birational to the projection $(C \times B)/G \to \mathbf{P}^1$. If $G$ acts trivially on $C$, then $\mathbf{P}^2$ would be birational to $C \times \mathbf{P}^1$, which is not possible.

This implies in particular that isotrivial pencils on $\mathbf{P}^2$ cannot be Lefschetz, 
because the automorphism group of a general member of a non-hyperelliptic Lefschetz pencil on a simply connected surface is trivial (see 10.6.18 in the book of Katz and Sarnak for a monodromy argument proving this fact).

Comment: Isotrivial pencils are *everywhere* non-transversal to the discriminant divisor, which is much stronger than being non-Lefschetz (i.e., that the pencil is *somewhere* non-transversal).

Comment: @JasonStarr, could you please elaborate this or point out a reference?

Comment: For a transverse crossing at $t_0\in C$, the first-order deformation to the versal deformation space of the node $x_0\in f^{-1}(t_0)$ is a nonzero quotient of the Kodaira-Spencer map $T_B\to h^1(R\pi_*\textit{RHom}(L_f,\mathcal{O}_X))$.  So the Kodaira-Spencer map is nonzero.  For a family of hypersurfaces, that target is locally free (on a neighborhood of $t_0$), so the family is nonisotrivial.

Comment: @JasonStarr Then a pencil with a node not in the base locus will give a nonisotrivial fibration, right?  Could you give any good reference to study the Kodaira-Spencer map with reasonable examples?